# Way to tell how many blocks are running on a particular RACScheduler

Tags: reactive-cocoa

This seems like a simple and easy question but I can't figure it out.

Is there a way to see how many blocks are executing on a RACScheduler??  Or if a single block was scheduled whether it has completed

Thanks in advance
Alan